# How to get nearby gas station and show direction to user with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, mapkitannotation

For a school project, I'm trying to get all nearby gas stations and create annotations for them and when the user click on one of these, I would like to get him the direction to go there.
this is the Maps controller that I implement by searching on internet and tutoriels:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

protocol MapsControllerDelegate : class {

    func mapsViewControllerDidSelectAnnotation(mapItem :MKMapItem)
}

class MapsController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var maps: MKMapView!
    weak var delegate :MapsControllerDelegate!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let regionInMeters: Double = 1000

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkLocationServices()


    }

    func setupLocationManager(){
        locationManager.delegate = self as! CLLocationManagerDelegate
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }

    func centerViewOnUserLocation(){
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate{
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
            maps.setRegion(region, animated: true)


        }
    }

    func checkLocationServices(){

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
            //setup the location manager.
            setupLocationManager()
            checkLocationAuthorization()
        }
        else{
            //Show alert let the user know how to do it.
        }
    }

    func checkLocationAuthorization(){
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus(){
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            maps.showsUserLocation = true
            centerViewOnUserLocation()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        case .denied:
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            break
        }
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {

        let annotationView = views.first!

        if let annotation = annotationView.annotation {
            if annotation is MKUserLocation {


                centerViewOnUserLocation()

                populateNearByPlaces()

            }
        }

    }



    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

        let annotation = view.annotation as! PlaceAnnotation
        self.delegate.mapsViewControllerDidSelectAnnotation(mapItem: annotation.mapItem)
    }

    func populateNearByPlaces(){

        print("Im heeeeeerrrrreeeeeee")
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate{
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)


        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Gas Station"
        request.region = region

        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start { (response, error) in

            guard let response = response else {
                return
            }

            for item in response.mapItems {

                print("I'm here")
                print(item)

                let annotation = PlaceAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
                annotation.title = item.name
                annotation.mapItem = item

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.maps.addAnnotation(annotation)
                }


            }

        }
    }

}
}
extension MapsController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else {return}
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: center, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
        maps.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        checkLocationAuthorization()
    }

}
}
```

I don't have any errors or the app stops working but I'm not getting the results expected. In the Maps scene I'm just getting the user's actual location on the map and that's it.

Comment: And where do you expect to get the gas stations from? What part of your code is failing?

Comment: func populateNearByPlaces() in 
let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Gas Station"

Comment: You return from closure when `response` is nil. That’s fine, but it would be wise to at least check if the `error` is not nil and at least print it to console - it might tell you whats going on. Also - are you certain there are gas stations in given region?

Comment: Yes, I have two gas stations near my place, I have on the output terminal "Couldn't retrieve region info" but it's showing me the exact location of my device.

Comment: The question is old, but: you don't tell MapKit how to render your annotations. Either use register or https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452045-mapview You find both ways in each tutorial.